# Restricting within netbeans

Tags: netbeans

We are an educational institution and we like te use netbeans within our environment. We want our students to learn and develop java within netbeans.
But as curious as students can be we would like to restrict a few things within netbeans such as changing the location where you save your projects.

Is this, at all, possible?

Greetings,
Luces

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to explicitly restrict the location(s) for saving a project in NetBeans, but even if there was you would presumably face a similar issue with other applications that the students might use.

The proper way to address the issue is for the system administrator to control file access based on a student's account/login.

Comment: We are using VDI right now to restrict students to a certain system, but its hella expensive so thats not an option, too bad we cant restrict it.

Comment: I can't imagine any alternatives to NetBeans (Eclipse, Intellij IDEA, etc.) would offer the functionality you want either. While VDI may be expensive it's a valid approach to solving your problem, but you don't have to use any third-party tool to solve this; you just need a competent sysadmin. I suggest raising this on superuser (https://superuser.com/) - it's not really an issue for SO.